# Are consumer brain-wave devices faster than keyboard/mouse?

Tags: neurology, computers, keyboard

I've seen advertisements for headsets such as the OCZ Neural Impulse Actuator, and recently there is a NeuroSky MindWave. Are these devices really capable of beating a keyboard and mouse for either high throughput or low latency?

Edit: For a simple example, just check the selling page for the OCZ NIA.

> Hone Your Reflexes
>     Where others have to practice reaction times, you
>   can use reflex-based game play to get the better of your opponents by
>   cutting your reaction time by 50%.

Comment: There is no doubt about latency, but not sure what you mean by throughput in that case?

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: I've seen some advertisements for this on various web sites over the past few days, absent any mention of side effects.  It seems to be a new technology:  http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=head-games-video-controller-brain

Comment: @Randolf, oh I know the systems exist. (Declaration: A friend used to work on these at Emotiv.) However, the question title suggests that someone, somewhere is claiming that they are faster than a keyboard/mouse. I have never seen anyone make that claim.

Comment: I believe it when Pro-SC2 players start using this and win.

Answer (score 8):

**Plausible reflex rates for limited functions.  But won't replace keyboard and mouse.**

A real answer could only come if someone tests the product in a laboratory and writes a solid review.  But here's my educated guess:

Many non-invasive brain-computer interfacing (BCI) systems are based on measuring [P300](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P300_%28neuroscience%29) signals with EEG, which take about 200-600ms.  So even *if* that amount of time gave you enough information, and you had efficient enough feature processing algorithms, you're not going to get much better than sub-second categorization of brainwaves -- so, a command rate of a dozen words per minute.  With current state of the art, looking at [these](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tanja/BCI/P300Speed_2000.pdf) [three](http://content.imamu.edu.sa/Scholars/it/VisualBasic/Serby-H%202005%20IEEETransNeuroSysRehabEng.pdf) [papers](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/101093/files/manuscript.pdf), subjects can only select about 4 or 5 characters per minute with P300-based BCI, or about 25 bits per minute.

*However*, the rates they are claiming for "reflexes" are plausible, because the OCZ NIA is **not a brainwave reader**: it's primarily based not on electroencephalography (EEG), but [electromyography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromyography) (EMG), which measures slight muscle movements.

EMG is frequently used in prosthetic limbs, and the signal is trivial to process compared to brainwaves.  For instance, [this review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1455479/) describes how to use wavelet transforms to preprocess data (read: efficient) and classify motor commands with neural networks.  I've also seen talks that describe doing the classification with Linear Discriminant Analysis (read: easy peasy).

So they could be spot-on with their claim, if we assume that twitching a face muscle takes less time than moving a mouse.  But it's more like strapping an extra button to your forhead and saying "do this when I twitch my eyebrow" than having it read your brainwaves and predict what you're trying to do -- so the romance is all but gone:  With those limitations, we're not eliminating the keyboard and mouse any time soon!

Comment: I'm not too sure about NIA since it's obsolete now and hard to find. It appears it was combined EMG/EEG device. The official description said "Working with the nia’s calibration program, the Actuator captures a variety of signals, such as facial muscle movement, eye movement, brain Alpha waves and Beta waves to control the game."The interface that can be seen you tube listed some alpha/beta waves as well https://youtu.be/l1H9V4TsQNM?t=667. Also and academic paper details only its EEG capabilities https://books.google.com/books?id=0aWpw1Db8oAC&pg=PA341

Comment: But then says "it uses combinations of classifications of EMG, EOG and EEG signals". EOG is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrooculography

Comment: As for some reasons to combine EMG and EEG, https://www.frontiersin.org/10.3389/conf.fncom.2015.56.00021/event_abstract